# How can i solve react native PhaseScriptExecution error

Tags: ios, react-native

Currently, I'm trying to run the iOS simulator with React Native, but the following error continues to occur.

```
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening ***.xcworkspace.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace ***.xcworkspace -configuration DebugDev -scheme ***Dev -destination id=***

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

...

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Copy\ XCFrameworks /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-anoalvrwljcacmebrbezdhvomyhd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/DebugDev-iphonesimulator/AirBridge.build/Script-46EB2E00015FD0.sh (in target 'AirBridge' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

I think **(in target 'AirBridge' from project 'Pods')** is the main cause of the error, so how can I solve this?